# How to record the time and duration of each question in java?

Tags: java, time, duration

I'm having a problem in recording the time and duration of quiz code with multiple choices.

This is the sample of the final output after answering all the questions.

Question # Your Answer  Remarks     Time        Duration

1       B   Wrong       10:32AM     30 seconds

2       A   Correct     10:33AM     22 seconds //repeat until Question #5

And this is code:

```
package timer;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class num4 {
public static void main (String [] args) throws InterruptedException{
    
   Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in); 
    Date date=new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat ft = 
  new SimpleDateFormat ("MMMM dd,yyyy '@'hh:mm a ");
   String one,two,three,four,five;
   String o,t,th,f,fi;
   int variable=0,wrong=0,seconds,minutes;
   final long startTime = System.nanoTime();
   System.out.println("Welcome to the rawr game!\n");
   Thread.sleep(1000);

   System.out.println("Question #1");
   System.out.println("What can one catch that is not thrown?");
   System.out.println("[A] rain");
   System.out.println("[B] a cold");
   System.out.println("[C] a secret");
   System.out.println("[D] snow");
   
    System.out.print("\nYour answer: ");
    one=scan.next();
    if(one.equals("B")){
        o="Correct";
        variable=variable+1;
    }else{
         o="Wrong";
         wrong=wrong+1;
    }
    
   System.out.println("\nQuestion #2");
   System.out.println("Pambansang Editor: ");
   System.out.println("[A] Netflix");
   System.out.println("[B] Youtube");
   System.out.println("[C] Facebook");
   System.out.println("[D] Instagram");
   
   System.out.print("\nYour answer: ");
   two=scan.next();
   if(two.equals("D")){
        t="Correct";
        variable=variable+1;
    }else{
         t="Wrong";
          wrong=wrong+1;
    }
   
   System.out.println("\nQuestion #3");
   System.out.println("Indian's Population in 2020");
   System.out.println("[A] 1.333 billion");
   System.out.println("[B] 1.300 billion");
   System.out.println("[C] 1.333 million");
   System.out.println("[D] 1.336 billion");
   
   System.out.print("\nYour answer: ");
   three=scan.next();
   
   if(three.equals("D")){
        th="Correct";
        variable=variable+1;
    }else{
         th="Wrong";
          wrong=wrong+1;
    }
   
   System.out.println("\nQuestion #4");
   System.out.println("Man's Bestfriend?");
   System.out.println("[A] dogs");
   System.out.println("[B] cat");
   System.out.println("[C] hamster");
   System.out.println("[D] none");
   
   System.out.print("\nYour answer: ");
   four=scan.next();
   if(four.equals("A")){
        f="Correct";
        variable=variable+1;
    }else{
         f="Wrong";
          wrong=wrong+1;
    }
   
   System.out.println("\nQuestion #5");
   System.out.println("Who steal the pot of soup in Episode 100 of Mark Angel Comedy? ");
   System.out.println("[A] Emmanuella");
   System.out.println("[B] The Iphone Girl");
   System.out.println("[C] Denilson");
   System.out.println("[D] Kbrown");
   
   System.out.print("\nYour answer: ");
   five=scan.next();
   if(five.equals("C")){
        fi="Correct";
        variable=variable+1;
    }else{
         fi="Wrong";
          wrong=wrong+1;
    }
   
   

  System.out.println("=====");
  System.out.println("Rawr quiz on " + ft.format(date));
  System.out.println("=====");
  
  System.out.println("Question #\tYour Answer\tRemarks\tTime\tDuration");
  System.out.println("1\t\t"+one+"\t\t"+o);
  System.out.println("2\t\t"+two+"\t\t"+t);
  System.out.println("3\t\t"+three+"\t\t"+th);  ///as you can see in this part
  System.out.println("4\t\t"+four+"\t\t"+f);    //// it's not complete
  System.out.println("5\t\t"+five+"\t\t"+fi);   ///I'm having trouble on how 
                                                /// to get the time and duration
  
  System.out.println("Number of Correct Answers: "+variable+"\t\tNumber of Wrong Answers: "+wrong);

  final long duration = System.nanoTime()- startTime;
  seconds =(int) (duration/1000000000);
  minutes= (int)  (seconds/60);
  if (minutes<=1){
      System.out.println("Total Duration: "+minutes+" minute");
  }else{
      System.out.println("Total Duration: "+minutes+" minutes");
  }
  

 }
 }
```

Comment: Do not longer use java.util.Date. Use the new java.time.* API

Answer (score 2):

Never use `Date`, `Calendar`, `SimpleDateFormat` classes. Use only *java.time* classes for your date-time handling.

As you start a question, capture the current moment as seen in UTC.

```
Instant start = Instant.now() ;
```

After the user answers, capture elapsed time.

```
Duration d = Duration.between( start , Instant.now() ) ;
```

Get total elapsed time as a count of whole seconds.

```
long seconds = d.toSeconds() ;
```

Adjust an `Instant` to a time zone for display to user.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

Generate text.

```
Locale locale = Locale.getDefault() ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedTime( FormatStyle.SHORT ).withLocale( locale ) ;
String output = zdt.format( f ) ;
```

Track the start and duration for each question in a pair of arrays. Or define your own class to track them together. In Java 16+ use a [record](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395) to define that class. You can define a record locally, or nested or separate.

```
record Response( Instant start , Duration duration ) {}
```

Define a list, and populate.

```
List< Response > reponses = new ArrayList<>() ;
…
responses.add( new Response( start , d ) ) ;
```

You could add more member fields to track the user’s response to each question, and to mark if correct or not.

```
record Response( int answer, boolean correct , Instant start , Duration duration ) {}
```

Comment: I would use `FormatStyle.SHORT` since the format in the OP's question is `hh:mmaa` (`10:32AM`/`10:33AM`), but I still like this answer. +1

Comment: @CardinalSystem Fair point; so changed. Thanks.

Comment: Basil Bourque thanks! I have tried it and this is one of the results PT7.912046S. How can I remove the PT and the decimals?

Comment: @Marie I showed `Duration#toSeconds` in my Answer.

Answer (score 0):

[Jens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3636601/jens) is right. You should be using the Java Time API. I suggest looking at [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html) and [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html). For each question you can use something like the following to calculate the duration:

```
LocalTime questionOneStart = LocalTime.now();
one = scan.next();
LocalTime questionOneEnd = LocalTime.now();
Duration questionOneDuration = Duration.between(questionOneStart, questionOneEnd);
```

Also, using LocalTime allows you to say exactly what time the user answered the question. I would use [`LocalTime#format(java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#format-java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter-) in your case:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mmaa");
String answerTimeString = questionOneEnd.format(formatter);
```

And to print the duration it took for the user to answer the question, you can use [`Duration#getSeconds`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#getSeconds--). You can also use [`toDays`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#toDays--), [`toHours`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#toHours--), [`toMinutes`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#toMinutes--), [`toMillis`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#toMillis--), and [`toNanos`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#toNanos--), depending on your requirements.

Comment: LocalTime questionOneStart = LocalTime.now();
one = scan.next();
LocalTime questionOneEnd = LocalTime.now();
Duration questionOneDuration = Duration.between(questionOneStart, questionOneEnd);
should i put that before each question?

Comment: I wouldn’t dare rely on `LocalTime`. Just in case the quiz is taken over midnight. Also if a summer time transition (DST transition) happens underway, the duration will be wrong. Still an answer with a lot of good information.

Comment: @Marie no. You do this every time you call `scan.next()`. Once before, once after. Just like I showed in my answer. That way you have the time when the user is asked the question the time the user answers.